# How can I download a copy of my heroku DB *from a certain day/time*?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

If I want to download a copy of my heroku database *the way it looked yesterday at 5:00pm* (for example), this is how I'm doing it today:

1. Create a new DB add-on with yesterday's data: `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:premium-2 --rollback MY_DATABASE --to '2018-10-01 05:00-06:00' --app=my-heroku-app`
2. Wait for that to finish: `heroku pg:wait`
3. Create a backup of that new database: `heroku pg:backups capture NAME_OF_NEWLY_CREATED_DB --app=my-heroku-app`.
4. Download that backup: 

   `` curl -o /path/to/download/to/my_backup.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url --app=my-heroku-app` ``
5. Delete my newly-created database

However, it seems like if I can create another *heroku* database using the data from yesterday at 5:00, it should be possible for me to *download* that data from yesterday more directly(?)  But I can't see a way to do it without creating the temporary heroku DB...

Is the above already the shortest path to success for me, or is there a faster/more-direct way (possibly sans the temporary DB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the shortest path to your desired outcome. There is no way to generate a dumpfile or similar from Heroku Postgres's point in time recovery system (ie `--rollback` functionality). If the desired time window is always the same you could schedule daily logical backups with `heroku pg:backups` and download those daily dumpfiles.